# What is the point of adding 'new' in front of a widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

For instance,

`return new Container(child: new Text('Hello'),);`

VS

`return Container(child: Text('Hello'),);`

I see people use both and was just wondering what the point is. Is it possible to use the same widget again somewhere or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the "new" keyword was once required in dart (the language used for flutter) for object instantiation, but this requirement was removed.

In order to prevent breaking old code, the keyword remains but is now optional. There is no difference between using it or not using it.

You may choose to use it if you want to make it clear that you are intending to do object instantiation and not call a function, as attempting to do `new somefunction() //not a constructor` will fail, though this is optional.

Comment: The mouse-over documentation deliberately shows it as (new) SomeClass so that you can verify you're looking at a constructor.  Quite nice of them.